# Is there any way in delphi to execute previously written code in a single line?

Tags: delphi

I'm a high school student taking programming as one of my subjects, so I'm rather new to Delphi.

I'm writing a game that requires the same (very long) block of code to be run when multiple different events occur. I was wondering if there was a way to write it at the beginning and call it in these different parts of the program, or perhaps get multiple senders to run the same event? The code sets the brush color of 42 different objects to different colors depending on what the user selects (the game is Risk) and when i try using a procedure it get errors for every object telling me it is undeclared.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    shpTerr1: TShape;

  private
{ Private declarations }
  public
    procedure CheckOwner;

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  iArmies, iTemp, i : integer;
  iSelected, iSelectedOld : integer;
  arrTerrArmies, arrTerrOwners : array[0..41] of integer;
  arrPlayerColour : array[0..3] of string;
  arrPlayers : array of string;
  AttackMode : boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure CheckOwner;
begin
  shpTerr1.Brush.Color := StringToColor('cl' + arrPlayerColour[arrTerrOwners[0]]);
end;
```

The error is with the TShape.
Any help?

Comment: Please provide a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: You could use a `PROCEDURE` and call it when you want where you want. Show some code please

Comment: When i try using a procedure i just get the error "undeclared identifier" even though it is declared. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You need to show the procedure, arrTerrOwners and arrPlayerColour declaration as well

Comment: Change procedure to form method (now it is regular procedure and know nothing about form fields like shpTerr1). Problem is with visibility scope

Comment: MBo, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: @Luke Sami already has posted example.

Comment: @MBo Hard to say with _New contributo_, he did not show the full code.

Comment: What problem is with TShape? Is `shpTerr1` really TShape control that you put on the form?

Comment: Add `Form1` (or what is the name of your form) before `shpTerr1` in your code. Or modify `CheckOwner` procedure in such a way to pass `shpTerr1` instance as an argument to this procedure.

Comment: @Dima i added in TForm1 and now it works, sorry about that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    shpTerr1: TShape;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure CheckOwner;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.CheckOwner;
begin
  shpTerr1.Brush.Color:= Color; // I don't know what is arrPlayerColour[arrTerrOwners[0]]
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckOwner;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I wasn't declaring the procedure in public, I was declaring under type, so I've changed that. Otherwise my code is the same and I'm getting an error saying that shpTerr1 is an undeclared identifier, I have no idea what could be going wrong..

Comment: @LukeWatermeyer, please, show us your code (add it to your question).

Comment: @LukeWatermeyer Do you have other units or just one?

Comment: @Dima I'm not including all 42 territories' code because I assume you don't want that clogging up your screen.

Comment: @Sami I do have one other unit but none of the variables or objects are declared there and I have already included it under "uses". could it still be causing issues?

Comment: @Sami So, it turns out im just a stupid little man who forgot to type in TForm1 before CheckOwner. Sorry to waste all of your time.

Comment: @Luke When you wrote `procedure XX;` in form class, press Ctrl-Shift-C to make auto class completion

Comment: @MBo one remark: this trick doesn't work in `Delphi Starter' :) Dont know about `Community Edition` though.